# Meaning of 気負わずに奮ってご参加ください

Tags: meaning, expressions, invitation

What does `気負わずに奮ってご参加ください` mean?
Is it like `気軽にご参加ください`?

Context: [an event information page](http://partake.in/events/e72dec20-90c9-4d6d-adf1-4b0f11cf2079) announcing pre-requisites for attendance:

> 前提知識
>
> Javaでのプログラミング経験がある方が分かりやすいかなという程度です。さらにAlfrescoを触ったことがあれば理解しやすいかもという程度です。
>
> 気負わずに奮ってご参加ください。

I guess it says `Even if you don't fit the pre-requisites, you are very welcome`, am I right?

Comment: `Is it like 気軽にご参加ください?` Yes, pretty much the same. Except 奮って would mean to "actively participate".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Pre-requisites: Should be easy to understand for people with Java programming experience. Also may be easy to understand for those who have worked with Alfresco as well. Take it easy and join us."

kiow-a-zu is negative form of the verb kiow- "to get worked up, be excited". furutte is an adverb meaning of one's own volition, positively etc.

Answer (score 3):

I would just translate it to "please do not hesitate to join us" as a free translation (意訳).

**奮う**

> 奮ってご来会下さい. 
>   You are cordially invited to the meeting.

(source: weblio http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A5%AE%E3%81%86)

**気負う**

> 人より上手に弾こうと気負うとかえって失敗する If you try too hard to play better than everyone else, you'll only end up making mistakes.

(source: Yahoo!Japan辞書 http://dic.yahoo.co.jp/dsearch/3/2na/00950300/)